# when to call syncState() on ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

In the android documentation http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html , its stated that

> *// Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.*

And `syncState()` is called inside `onPostCreate` method. But I experimented by calling the method on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object inside `onCreate` method and found no difference. Why so ? I think there must be some situations for which my experiment will fail. Which are those situations ?